# Install Nvidia Drivers on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia

OK, i've managed to get them installed, but i'm not 100% clear how I actually did this and why it actually worked. Hopefully someone can help explain.

Here's what I ran as commands to get this working;

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-396

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

- (i think...) *

So, now this is working. Why did it work, how did it work, why, how?

The above is from a few hours of researching/testing/experimenting. Seems to work, but I'd love to know why it works... I can't seem to find any useful information online about how all these pieces of the puzzle fit together.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
```

Adds the [Personal Package Archive](https://itsfoss.com/ppa-guide/) ([more](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ubuntu-ppa-technology-explained/)) where packages for such drivers may be obtained for Ubuntu installs.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Looks at all packages not on your system and [updates them](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) if out of date or adds them if absent.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-396
```

Install the driver package for NVIDIA #396, so it can be added to the kernel next.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Tells the installed driver package to add itself to your kernel.

You may also find https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux and https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu/ useful in understanding proprietary (i.e., not Open Source) installation better.

Comment: Perfect information, thanks. One follow on question, what is the difference between installing the driver and adding it to the OS - Sounds like the same thing to me? But I guess not.

Comment: See above. Windows combines steps 3 & 4, whereas they're separate in Linux.

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense now :-) Much appreciated!