# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Server freezes after running update

Tags: server, 18.04, nvidia

I've done a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Server on my workstation, and run into a peculiar issue. Every time I do an install/update of the base system:

```
apt-get update
```

the system freezes on reboot. That is, the machine just hangs with a blank screen. However, if I then do a CMOS reset on my motherboard, the OS then comes back up. I'm not sure how to diagnose this further. I've checked /var/log/syslog and don't see anything out of the ordinary (perhaps I don't know what to look for?). I've done the usual things for grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=off nomodeset"
```

I do have an NVIDIA card (Titan RTX) in the system, and my motherboard is an ASUS SAGE X299.

Please let me know how to diagnose this further. It's not practical to keep doing CMOS resets. Thanks!

Comment: You need nomodeset to boot before you install nVidia driver, but once driver installed, you need to remove nVidia driver. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2397473

Comment: @oldfred Once the driver is installed you need to remove `nomodeset`, not the driver.

Comment: Sorry, I did mean remove nomodeset boot parameter.

Comment: Did you have installed `dkms`? I think that problem is, that without `dkms` `nvidia` proprietary driver is not installed for newer `linux-kernel`. So try to install `dkms` and (maybe) reinstall `nvidia` drivers.

Comment: It could be that this is related to the UEFI cr*p on your mainboard. Check if there is a newer BIOS version available and update the BIOS, just to make sure it is not related to an old UEFI BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the **/var/log/install/syslog** file instead of /var/log/syslog because that's where the OS installation log is stored. See where the log ends. My log for *Ubuntu-18.04.3-server* from successful installation ends with following lines:

```
Nov 20 13:01:37 in-target: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:9 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
Nov 20 13:01:37 in-target:
Nov 20 13:01:37 finish-install: info: Running /usr/lib/finish-install.d/65partman-md
Nov 20 13:01:37 finish-install: info: Running /usr/lib/finish-install.d/70mtab
Nov 20 13:01:37 finish-install: info: Running /usr/lib/finish-install.d/90base-installer
Nov 20 13:01:37 finish-install: info: Running /usr/lib/finish-install.d/90console
Nov 20 13:01:37 finish-install: info: Running /usr/lib/finish-install.d/94random-seed
Nov 20 13:01:37 finish-install: info: Running /usr/lib/finish-install.d/94save-logs
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we don’t have to make any permanent changes to GRUB.

Change it back to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Secondly, while booting press <kbd>e</kbd> on the GRUB menu and add `nomodeset` just at the end of quiet splash nomodeset $vt... Then press either <kbd>F10</kbd> key or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

Type `journalctl -xb` and check the end of the lines to find any issue if you could...

Otherwise, try connecting to wifi or internet...

Then run `sudo apt update --fix-missing && sudo apt full-upgrade`.

First, detect the model of your Nvidia graphic card and the recommended driver. To do so execute:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

From the output of the above command, we can conclude that the current system has so and so Nvidia graphic card then we can install the recommended driver.

If we agree with the recommendation then we can use `ubuntu-drivers` command again to install all recommended drivers:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstal
```

This command tells the installed driver package to add itself to your kernel.

Alternatively, we can install the desired driver selectively using the apt command. For example:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-340
```

Once the installation is concluded, we can reboot the system and we are done.

Also, we can try another method posted on [Install Nvidia Drivers on Ubuntu Server 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157647/install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-server-18-04).

Comment: How can we make permanent changes to grub and modify the boot process permanently. For fixing things all we need is temporary changes in grub. Once fixed we've to continue with the normal boot process.

Comment: yes dont have to